# Let G be a noncyclic group of order 121. How many subgroups does G have? Can you generalize?

Tags: group-theory

I get that there can only be subgroups of order 1, 11, 121. But how do you account for the fact that there would only be 10 + e elements in every subgroup; since e is repeated in every subgroup, there are only 10 unique elements in every subgroup, so should there be 12 groups of order 11, one group of order 1, 121?

Answer (score 2):

A group of order $p^2$ is abelian since its center is non trivial because it is a $p$ group and so $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ is cyclic.

So by the fundamental theorem for finite abelian groups there are only two possible groups:

$\mathbb Z_{121}$ and $\mathbb Z_{11}\times \mathbb Z_{11}$.

Cyclic groups have exactly one subgroup of each order that divides the order of the group. So $\mathbb Z_{121}$ has $3$ subgroups ($\mathbb Z_{11}$ and the two trivial subgroups).

The non-trivial subgroups of $\mathbb Z_{11}\times \mathbb Z_{11}$ have order $11$. The non-trivial elements of $\mathbb Z_{11}$ also have order $11$. So each subgroup is generated by a non-identity element. Since each subgroup contains $10$ non identity elements the number of subgroups is $\frac{120}{10}=12$. Adding the two trivial ones we have $14$.